# Powershell counting same values from csv

Tags: powershell, csv, count

Using PowerShell, I can import the CSV file and count how many objects are equal to "a". For example,

```
@(Import-csv location | where-Object{$_.id -eq "a"}).Count
```

Is there a way to go through every column and row looking for the same String "a" and adding onto count? Or do I have to do the same command over and over for every column, just with a different keyword?

Comment: If you are just trying to count the occurrences of a string in a CSV file import it as text not as a CSV and match the string that way. Or better, use Select-String on the file and specify the -allmatches parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made a dummy file that contains 5 columns of people names. Now to show you how the process will work I will show you how often the text "Ann" appears in any field.

```
$file = "C:\temp\MOCK_DATA (3).csv"
gc $file | %{$_ -split ","} | Group-Object | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "Ann*"}
```

Don't focus on the code but the output below.

```
Count Name  Group                          
----- ----  -----                          
    5 Ann   {Ann, Ann, Ann, Ann...}        
    9 Anne  {Anne, Anne, Anne, Anne...}    
   12 Annie {Annie, Annie, Annie, Annie...}
   19 Anna  {Anna, Anna, Anna, Anna...}
```

"Ann" appears 5 times on it's own. However it is a part of other names as well. Lets use a simple regex to find all the values that are only "Ann".

```
(select-string -Path 'C:\temp\MOCK_DATA (3).csv' -Pattern "\bAnn\b" -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches).Count
```

That will return 5 since `\b` is for a word boundary. In essence it is only looking at what is between commas or beginning or end of each line. This omits results like "Anna" and "Annie" that you might have. `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches` is important to have if you have more than one match on a single line.

**Small Caveat**

It should not matter but in trying to keep the code simple it is possible that your header could match with the value you are looking for. Not likely which is why I don't account for it. If that is a possibility then we could use `Get-Content` instead with a `Select -Skip 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try cycling through properties like this:

```
(Import-Csv location | %{$record = $_; $record | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | 
    ?{$record.$($_.Name) -eq 'a';}}).Count
```