# Powershell looking through all columns searching for a keyword

Tags: powershell, csv, search

Using powershell, lets say I have a csv file that contains

```
fname,lname,id,etc..
```

Is there a way to use `where-object` to look through all of the columns instead of just one.

For example, instead of doing:

```
Import-csv location |where-Object {$_.fname -eq "hi"}
```

next line:

```
Import-csv location |where-Object {$_.lname -eq "hi"} and so on.
```

It would be something like:

```
Import-csv location |where-Object {ANY -eq "hi"}
```

Comment: I will be counting the total, that why i need to do this

Comment: You asked this exact same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529154/powershell-counting-same-values-from-csv

Comment: How is this different then you last question? This should be closed outright and if you don't like the answer you got there update your question and we can look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could iterate over `$_.psobject.Properties` to inspect every column and return `$true` if one of them matches:

```
Import-Csv document.csv |Where-Object {
    foreach($p in ($_.psobject.Properties |? {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'})) {
        if($p.Value -match "hi"){ $true }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the column headings / property names are irrelevant and all you care about is the values, you can handle it as text:

```
Get-Content c:\somedir\somefile.csv |
Where {$_ -like '*"hi"*'}
```

If you're just after a count, you can just count the matches.  If you want objects, you can run the matched lines through `convertfrom-csv`.