# Powershell using where-object

Tags: powershell, csv, where-clause

I am using Powershell and am having trouble with the `Where-Object` cmdlet. I currently `select *` and then want to only output when a field is equal to `Alabama`. This field could be under any column, not just one.

This is what I have:

```
select * | where {$_.state_name -eq 'Alabama'} .
```

This works for state_name, but i cant get all columns without doing them individually. I've tried `where{$_ -eq....}` but that doesn't work.

Comment: From what are you `select`ing? Did you try `$_.state_name` instead? Note the period `.` after `$_`

Comment: That was a typo. I meant $_. Im trying to select all where propertyname= 'Alabama'

Comment: This sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529154/powershell-counting-same-values-from-csv/29537226#29537226 as well

Answer (score 3):

Kind of a hack, but:

```
select * | where {($_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)[1] -like '*"Alabama"*'}
```

Comment: Nah, not much of a hack IMO. The only option is to somehow concatenate all the fields together then check the concatenated value for the string. CSV is a decent way to do that.

Comment: I can think of one edge case that would cause a problem. If there is a property name that matched the search string that would be a problem.

Comment: @EBGreen.  I thought of that, and added the [1] to slice off just the data row.

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate over all object's properties and check if it contains word 'Alabama'.

Example:

```powershell
# Import CSV file and feed it to the pipeline
Import-Csv -Path .\My.csv |
    # For each object
    ForEach-Object {
        # Psobject.Properties returns all object properties
        # (Psobject.Properties).Value returns only properties' values
        # -contains operator checks if array of values contains exact string 'Alabama'
        # You can also use -like operator with wildcards, i.e. -like '*labama'
        if(($_.PSObject.Properties).Value -contains 'Alabama')
        {
            # If any of the object properties contain word 'Alabama',
            # write it to the pipeline, else do nothing.
            $_
        }
    }
```

Comment: This could just be reduced to `Import-Csv C:\Temp\data.csv | Where-Object{($_.PSObject.Properties).Value -contains 'Alabama'}`

Comment: I think this is a true answer to the question, as it natively pulls the needed properties/values from the object in flight, rather than effectively re-importing the values, as the other answer does.

Comment: @Matt +1, I've missed that.